# Why cant I using facebook graph api to upload photo a facebook group I created

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to upload photo to a Facebook group i created. I could not find any edges that lets me do it. Is there a way this can be accomplished. I want to be able to do this using android sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

To post to group you have to use app access token with publish_actions, user_groups permissions, I have done with PHP not android but I think this link could help you

To use publish_actions you have to review your app to Facebook before you can publish your app

Hope this help